# Magento 2 - How to regenerate url_rewrite table?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, indexer

I truncated the whole `url_rewrite` table from phpMyAdmin.

I thought that it will regenerate if I execute `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but it doesn't.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check this out https://firebearstudio.com/blog/regenerate-url-rewrites-magento-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look to this one https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites :

```
bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not generate URL's for the categories. But it is a start. Thank you!